# VS Code variables; how do I refer to subordinate fields?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Given the following settings.json:

```
{
    "zopeneditor.propertygroups": [ 
        { 
            "name": "mvs-members",
            "type": "mvs",
            "syslib": ["Z85779.CPY"],
        }
    ],
    "editor.fontSize": 14
}
```

I can use the following:

```
${config:editor.fontSize}
```

But how do I refer to one of the fields subordinate to zopeneditor.propertygroups?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-json-property